# How to make a VBA function which works as boolean?

Tags: vba, excel

I have given a list of names. For example:

```
Hanna-liis
Hanna-maria
Hanna-liina
Helgi-maie
Helju-mai
```

And then I have this name which is given with symbols H???-m???.
I have to make a function which works as boolean and the function has to answer if the words match the one which is in symbols- true or false.

For example Helgi-maie matches H???-m??? but Helju-mai doesnt. So Helgi-maie is true and helju-mai is false.

I came up with this

```
Function võrdlus(sõna, mask) As Boolean 
    võrdlus=true or false 
    If Left("A4", 1) = Left("B1", 1) And Left("A4", 7) = Left("B1", 7) Then
        võrdlus = True 
    Else 
        võrdlus = False 
    End If
```

This is all I got now. But it gives me that all the answers are correct.

Comment: Your example is incorrect. If the first character is "H" and the 7th character is "m" then your function returns `true`

Comment: For example Helgi-maie matches H???-m??? and Helju-mai does. So Helgi-maie is true and helju-mai is true.

Comment: No it is not, because one questionmark is equal to one letter, but helju-mai means it is h???-m??, so one less. But the problem isnt in names, it is in the code.

Comment: I understand how ??? works, but your code isn't using that and if it was, then both would be false.

Comment: Oh I guess I understood now. I have to put how many letter can a name contain also...

Comment: I dont know how to put that in there

Comment: Right now it gives me that all the answers are ture

Comment: `len(value)` is how to find out how many characters are in a name

Comment: Your code is only checking 2 cells against each other, it isn't looking at multiple cells against 1.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to keep on trying.

Comment: I'm sure you don't need a function for this, it can be done in a formula

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can just use a formula as opposed to a VBA function:

`=IFERROR(IF(AND(SEARCH(A4,B1)<>0,LEN(A4)=LEN(B1)),"TRUE","FALSE"),"FALSE")`

Where `A4` is the symbol version of the name and `B1` is the full name.

Comment: I would, but we have to do it in VBA because our teacher asked to do it in VBA and to do it as a boolean function.

Answer (score 0):

Life will get a lot easier if you research Regular Expressions... Add a reference in your project to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 and you can use code like this

```
Private Function checkByRegex(byVal strPattern, byVal strInput)       
    Dim regEx As New RegExp

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
            checkByRegex = True
        Else
            checkBYRegex = False
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

and call it with `checkByRegex("H???-m???","Helju-maie")` for example

Comment: I am going to try this also. But our teacher asked us to do it as a boolean function.

Comment: It IS a boolean function.  See how it is set to either True or False?  That's what boolean means.  Declare a variable `result` and call the function with `result = checkByRegex(blah, blah)` and `result` will hold the boolean value of the funciton.  Though we're not really supposed to help with homework!

Answer (score 0):

Further clarifying Dave's reply, make a function that is true/false based on the regEx results and call that from a subroutine which you can bind to a button or menu option:

```
Private Sub CheckName()
    checkByRegEx(strPattern, StrInput)
End Sub

Private Function checkByRegex(ByVal strPattern As string, ByVal strInput As String) AS Boolean
    Dim regEx         As New RegExp

    If strPattern <> "" Then
          With regEx
              .Global = True
              .MultiLine = True
              .IgnoreCase = False
              .Pattern = strPattern
          End With

          checkByRegEx = regEx.Test(strInput)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Going to try this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub võrdlus()
    Dim checkFormat As String

    checkFormat = Range("A4").Value
    For i = 1 To Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        checkValue = Range("B" & i).Value
        If checkValue Like checkFormat And Len(checkValue) = 10 Then
            Range("C" & i).Value = True
        Else
            Range("C" & i).Value = False
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Depending on where the values are located, you will need to adjust the ranges, but this will work.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what exactly you want to do but here is my version:

```
               'Once pressed, loop through the entire list and check is criteria is met
            'return TRUE or FALSE when word starts with an H and has a length of 5 AND
            'the second word starts with m with a length of 4
            Sub Button1_Click()
                For i = 1 To Sheet1.Range("C1").Value
                    Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = checkWord(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value)
                Next i
            End Sub

            'Chec if value evaluates to TRUE or FALSE
            Function checkWord(ByVal word As String) As Boolean
                Dim wordSplit As Variant ' An array where word is split up

                'Split word with delimiter "-"
                wordSplit = Split(word, "-")

                'The array now holds...
                'EXAMPLE:
                'wordSplit(0) = Helgi
                'wordSplit(1) = maie
                'len(Helgi) = 5
                'len(maie) = 4
                'FUNCTION should return TRUE

                'First word in array starts with a "H"?
                If InStr(1, wordSplit(0), "H", vbBinaryCompare) = 1 Then
                    'Does it have a length of 5?
                    If Len(wordSplit(0)) = 5 Then
                        'The first 2 criteria are correct,
                        'now check if 2nd word starts with a "m"
                        If InStr(1, wordSplit(1), "m", vbBinaryCompare) = 1 Then
                            'If true, does it have a length of 4?
                            If Len(wordSplit(1)) = 4 Then
                                checkWord = "TRUE"
                            Else 'No it doesnt
                                checkWord = "FALSE"
                            End If
                        'No it does not start with "m"
                        Else
                            checkWord = "FALSE"
                        End If
                    'Not it is not 5 letters long
                    Else
                        checkWord = "FALSE"
                    End If
                End If
            End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Code only answers should be avoided.

Comment: I can't explain something if i am not sure what he wanted. So I gave him a sample code where he can copy and paste it in his own workbook and test it. Then he can come back and say yes that's exactly what I wanted or no it's somewhat what I wanted. I will remember that for next time.

Comment: If you're not sure what he wanted, the proper thing to do is ask for clarifications in the comments or downvote the question or flag it for being unclear or too broad.